# Python: how can I read and store data, which have changing column number, to list?

Tags: python

My data looks following

```
...
 5 4 3 16 22 247 0         1.168         0.911         0.944         3.205         0.000         0.562
 6 4 4 17 154 93 309 0         0.930         0.919         0.903         0.917         3.852         0.000         1.419
 7 3 2 233 311 0         0.936         0.932         1.874         2.000        -0.807
...
```

Data is made up of integers and floats, but I hope to just gather the integers, and get the elements of them and use them. However, this data's total number of columns are changing. Luckily, this data's 3rd column is the number of next columns. For example, 1st line have '3' in 3rd column, which have 3 integers following. Next line have '4' in 3rd column, so that line have 4 following integers after 3rd line. Last line have '2', so the line have 2 following integers.

Previously, I wrote a code as make empty list, and put data into the list, such as

```
   at_index = [None]*nline
   at_type = [None]*nline
   num_of_bonds = [None]*nline
   neighbor_id1 = [None]*nline
   neighbor_id2 = [None]*nline
   neighbor_id3 = [None]*nline
   neighbor_id4 = [None]*nline
   neighbor_id5 = [None]*nline
   for i1 in nlines:
      ### Split each line based on spaces
          line = data_lines[i1].split()
          at_index[i1] = int(line[0])
          at_type[i1] = int(line[1])
          num_of_bonds[i1] = int(line[2])
          if num_of_bonds[i1] == 2:
             neighbor_id1[i1] = int(line[3])
             neighbor_id2[i1] = int(line[4])
          if num_of_bonds[i1] == 3:
             neighbor_id1[i1] = int(line[3])
             neighbor_id2[i1] = int(line[4])
             neighbor_id3[i1] = int(line[5])
          if num_of_bonds[i1] == 4:
             neighbor_id1[i1] = int(line[3])
             neighbor_id2[i1] = int(line[4])
             neighbor_id3[i1] = int(line[5])
             neighbor_id4[i1] = int(line[6])
```

But this attempt failed, because all data in 'neighbor_id1' to 'neighbor_id4' was overwritten by the last if loop, "num_ofbonds[i1] == 4" condition. It seems I need to differentiate the name of lists, such as 'neighbor1_id1', and 'neighbor4_id3', but that requires me to make all those empty arrays before I do something.

How can I read and store those data which have 'dynamic number of columns; in clean and neat way, and still, I could use elements from each columns? Thank you

Best,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need for output :

```
>>> lines = ['5 4 3 16 22 247 0 1.168 0.911 0.944 3.205 0.000 0.562',
     '6 4 4 17 154 93 309 0 0.930 0.919 0.903 0.917 3.852 0.000 1.419',
     '7 3 2 233 311 0 0.936 0.932 1.874 2.000 -0.807']
>>> def getInt(lines):
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        items = line.split()
        for i in range(1,int(items[2])+1):
            result.append(items[2+i])
    return result

>>> res = getInt(lines)
>>> res
['16', '22', '247', '17', '154', '93', '309', '233', '311']
>>>
```

to get details values per row, you can modify the code like this :

```
>>> def getInt(lines):
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        row = []
        items = line.split()
        for i in range(1,int(items[2])+1):
            row.append(items[2+i])
        result.append(row)
    return result

>>> res = getInt(lines)
>>> res
[['16', '22', '247'], ['17', '154', '93', '309'], ['233', '311']]
>>> res[0]
['16', '22', '247']
```

as per your request,
1. we need to iterate each item in row/line and column and we do it manually, without using enumerate function.
2. keep row and column position, and compare the value
3. in last script I forgot to type cast the value to int, read comment in following code

```
>>> lines = ['5 4 3 16 22 247 0 1.168 0.911 0.944 3.205 0.000 0.562',
     '6 4 4 17 154 233 309 0 0.930 0.919 0.903 0.917 3.852 0.000 1.419',
     '7 3 2 233 311 0 0.936 0.932 1.874 2.000 -0.807']
>>> def getInt(lines):
    result = []
    for line in lines:
        row = []
        items = line.split()
        for i in range(1,int(items[2])+1):
            row.append(int(items[2+i])) # old line row.append(items[2+i])
        result.append(row)
    return result

>>> def getPos(result, item):
    row_pos = 0
    for i in result:
        row_pos +=1
        for j in range(len(i)):
            if i[j]==item:
                print("Item %s found in position : (%s,%s)" % (item, row_pos,j))

>>> res = getInt(lines)
>>> getPos(res, 22)
Item 22 found in position : (1,1)
>>> getPos(res, 233)
Item 233 found in position : (2,2)
Item 233 found in position : (3,0)
```

I hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks, but I hope to put each columns of data to the list. But this really helps me.

Comment: Thank you very much. May I ask one last question? How can I approach to the each element of that 'res' matrix? I hope to iterate over some data blocks, for each line and columns. So I need to get specific elements under some conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Just split, slice and dice

Its just a matter of fact that you need to know

1. How to split a string to fields separated by spaces using `str.split`
2. How slicing and indexing works

**Implementation**

```
for line in st.splitlines():
    line = line.split()
    line = line[:3+int(line[2])]
    print line
```

Extend this idea to your problem

Comment: I tried but couldn't get this. Any more hints? Problem is, my data have integer and floats, and number of columns are changing. This two fact hurts my code a lot.

Comment: Please, help me. Could you at least tell me my way of reading columns is ok?