# python: how can I read elements of 2d dynamic lists?

Tags: python, string, list, integer

I have following data

```
['1', '4', '4', '244', '263', '704', '952']
['2', '4', '4', '215', '172', '305', '33']
['3', '4', '4', '344', '279', '377', '1945']
['4', '4', '4', '66', '79', '169', '150']
['5', '4', '3', '16', '22', '247']
['6', '4', '4', '17', '154', '93', '309']
['7', '3', '2', '233', '311']
['8', '3', '1', '15']
['9', '3', '2', '55', '102']
.....
```

Total 200 lines, made up of 4 of 50-line data blocks. Similar formatted data block repeats 4 times inside file. How can I indexing this data, and approach to each of the elements by blcok-wise, and column/line wise inside each blocks? Should I need to orthogonalize this data?

I'm stucked from str to int step. I tried to apply numpy.array or map, but they were not working.

Answer (score 3):

Once you have your list of list

```
l = [['1', '4', '4', '244', '263', '704', '952'],
     ['2', '4', '4', '215', '172', '305', '33'],
     ['3', '4', '4', '344', '279', '377', '1945'],
     ['4', '4', '4', '66', '79', '169', '150'],
     ['5', '4', '3', '16', '22', '247'],
     ['6', '4', '4', '17', '154', '93', '309'],
     ['7', '3', '2', '233', '311'],
     ['8', '3', '1', '15'],
     ['9', '3', '2', '55', '102']]
```

Use `map` within a list comprehension

```
intList = [map(int, sublist) for sublist in l]
```

Result

```
>>> intList
[[1, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952],
 [2, 4, 4, 215, 172, 305, 33],
 [3, 4, 4, 344, 279, 377, 1945],
 [4, 4, 4, 66, 79, 169, 150],
 [5, 4, 3, 16, 22, 247],
 [6, 4, 4, 17, 154, 93, 309],
 [7, 3, 2, 233, 311],
 [8, 3, 1, 15],
 [9, 3, 2, 55, 102]]
```

Comment: Oh, now I'm seeing this clear. My error was because my data was nested list-list structure, so you used sublist concept to map the data. Great! Now I know why my map() was not working. Is indexing of these dynamic data would same way with indexing orthogonal data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, what do you mean by orthogonal data? Could you show an example?

Comment: Now, in my data, number of columns are varying. My "orthogonalize" means make perfect m x n matrix shape, Such as [5 4 3 16 22 247 0 0]. I hope to indexing all data by datablock, line and column, and approach to the each elements using nested for-loops.

Comment: No that should not be necessary. The above code should work even if the lists are of different lengths.

Comment: Thank you very much, can I have one more question? How can I store data column-wise in result data?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "orthogonalize", may be this is what you looking for,

```
>>> li = [[1, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952], [2, 4, 4, 215, 172, 305, 33], [3, 4, 4, 344, 279, 377, 1945], [4, 4, 4, 66, 79, 169, 150], [5, 4, 3, 16, 22, 247], [6, 4, 4, 17, 154, 93, 309], [7, 3, 2, 233, 311], [8, 3, 1, 15], [9, 3, 2, 55, 102]]
>>> def orthogonalize(li):
    max_col = max(len(x) for x in li) + 1
    for l in li:
        for i in range(max_col-len(l)):
            l.append(0)


>>> orthogonalize(li)
>>> li
[[1, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952, 0], [2, 4, 4, 215, 172, 305, 33, 0], [3, 4, 4, 344, 279, 377, 1945, 0], [4, 4, 4, 66, 79, 169, 150, 0], [5, 4, 3, 16, 22, 247, 0, 0], [6, 4, 4, 17, 154, 93, 309, 0], [7, 3, 2, 233, 311, 0, 0, 0], [8, 3, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 3, 2, 55, 102, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> li[5]
[6, 4, 4, 17, 154, 93, 309, 0]
>>> li[6]
[7, 3, 2, 233, 311, 0, 0, 0]
>>>
```

Edit based on your additional requirement:

I have to make assumption due to my limitation of understanding, 
that your data is 2d but you want to access it in 3d using block#, line# and column# because I can not find block identifier in your data. And you've processed your data

```
>>> def getData(data, block, line, column = None):
    """
     Index start from 0 for block, line and column
     getData(data, 0,1,1)
       => block# is 0 it will be processed as is
       => it will read value of line#1, column#1 
     getData(data, 1,1,1)
       => block# is 1 it will be convert to line number = 50*(block)+line
       => it will read value of line#51, column#1


    """
    if column is None:
        return data[50*(block)+line]
    else:    
        return data[50*(block)+line][column]

>>> d = [[1, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952, 0],
[2, 4, 4, 215, 172, 305, 33, 0],
[3, 4, 4, 344, 279, 377, 1945, 0],
............
[51, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952, 0],
[52, 4, 4, 215, 172, 305, 33, 0],
[53, 4, 4, 344, 279, 377, 1945, 0],
[54, 4, 4, 66, 79, 169, 150, 0],
[55, 4, 3, 16, 22, 247, 0, 0],
[56, 4, 4, 17, 154, 93, 309, 0],
[57, 3, 2, 233, 311, 0, 0, 0],
[58, 3, 1, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[59, 3, 2, 55, 102, 0, 0, 0],
[60, 4, 4, 304, 209, 307, 945, 0]]
>>> getData(d, 0, 0)
[1, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952, 0]
>>> getData(d, 0, 0, 3)
244
>>> getData(d, 1, 0)
[51, 4, 4, 244, 263, 704, 952, 0]
>>> getData(d, 1, 0, 4)
263
```

Comment: Thank you. This also helps me a lot. I think I really need to make a habit to use def

Comment: I have a question. Regardless of 'orthogonalization', How can I split these data one by one? I tried split and strip, but both failed. I want to read each of element one by one.

Comment: @exsonic01, why you need to split it ? you can access the result list in matrix, ex : li[0][0] => 1, li[1][1] => 4. If you need for specific value, i already give you sample code in [read and store data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133642/python-how-can-i-read-and-store-data-which-have-changing-column-number-to-lis/26134019#26134019)

Comment: I hope to do something with elements, for each datablock, for each coulmn and each line. Im get used to fortran style indexing, so I was looking for way to split lines and do something by column and line.

Comment: Thank you very much for helps. Can I do nested for and if loops with these lists? Im not sure how can I indexing those lists

Comment: I'm little bit confuse, try to read your initial question once more, if your data is made up of 4 blocks, and each block contain 50 lines, so can I presume that its 3d data. do you want to read it by data[#block][#line][#column] ?

Comment: I was trying myself like 
for block in datablock: 
    for lines in range_numlines:
        data[i] = originaldata.split()
        number = data[0].... 

Something like this, so that I could approach to the data for each data block, for each line, per each column, but split is not working here. I think your way of data[block][line][column] would also same with my intention.

And then For all data blcok, For all lines, If column[2] == 4 then do something

Comment: Or, could you teach me how can I iterate something in data[block][line][column]?

Comment: Thank you very much for all those helps.

Comment: How can I use index numbers? I need to use indices of all elements, and do some if loops and for loops.

Comment: Can you give us more information regarding your expectation, in pseudo code or fortran style indexing as you mention, and please include some output example.

Comment: Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128118/how-can-i-replace-the-element-of-a-list-and-use-list-elements-in-for-if-loops This link contains brief explanation of my intention. Hope that helps.